# Flex- 3 conditions for 3 possible values for a variable

Tags: java, apache-flex, coding-style, programming-languages, flex3

I have three conditions for three possible values for a variable. In the mxml code i would like to display a different datagrid for each instance.
Is there a shorter way than writing three boolean functions for each possible value, and then using the boolean value returned by the method as a parameter for whether each datagrid will be loaded?

Comment: If these are complicated conditionals; you may be able to simplify them w/ a K-map.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map But, beyond that I don't understand what you're not understanding.  If there are three different outputs, you're going to need three different conditions.

Comment: why would you 'display a different datagrid for each instance'?  What's the point? Why not the same instance, just changing the data/columns?  What exactly is the functionality you want?

Comment: I agree with J_A_X. What's the point in having three different datagrids where you can work with just one switching their dataproviders and manipulating columns programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly bind the visible and includeInLayout properties within the MXML definition of the grid to either a boolean or to an expression that evaluates to a boolean.  The only limitation is that you have to be able to express the evaluation as a single statement.  You can however use compound conditions you just can't do something like say store a variable then check against it.  You'd pull this off simply like this:

```
<mx:DataGrid visible="{myObject=='state1'}" includeInLayout="{myObject=='state1'}"/>
<mx:DataGrid visible="{myObject=='state2'}" includeInLayout="{myObject=='state2'}"/>
<mx:DataGrid visible="{myObject=='state3'}" includeInLayout="{myObject=='state3'}"/>
```

Note this will still cause all three grids to be created as a result of their parent container being created.  Alternatively you can actually use states to add or remove particular grids... ultimately the best option is to create one grid definition and change the properties on it conditionally based on the state.  There are many ways to solve this but some are better than others so consider looking into Flex in a week videos and UIComponent life cycle to be sure you understand the implications of your choice.

Also to note if you need a complex condition since you're in XML you'll need to use

> &amp;

for each ampersand like

```
<mx:DataGrid visible="{myObject=='state3'&amp;&amp;someOtherThing=='whatever'}" includeInLayout="{myObject=='state3'&amp;&amp;someOtherThing=='whatever'}"/>
```

Last Edit I recommend using this:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=using_states_3.html

Comment: I wouldn't do this.  You're now creating 3 instances of a DataGrid even if only one is showing or even needed.

Comment: I explained that the first method isn't the best, and explained better options, read further before adding comments please.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I didn't read the last part, but even the last part is flawed because it doesn't solve that fact that the datagrid should 'change' depending on the data.  You're adding a lot more binding to a situation where binding is probably isn't needing.

Comment: thanks but the different datagrids are needed as they are in a completely different format for each condition- i considered using view states for this but it does not seem possible as the visual controls are completely different, and as such it is not possible to simply override a 'base state'. i wonder if it would be possible to use view stacks instead or just set the visibility on the visual components in accordance with the conditions?

Comment: Agreed I didn't post a single great solution each of these have their issues and advantages, I agree the best option is to have one instance of the control and change out the properties on it even if they are fairly disparate unless you're willing to take the performance hit up front for a possible gain in switching between them.